# Oracle update statement using PowerShell

Tags: oracle, powershell, dml

I'm trying to run a simple Oracle UPDATE statement using powershell and OracleDataAdapter.
I got stuck in the execution part..
please advise on how to proceed from here...

```
$userName1="user1"
$password1="password1"
$Server1="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_exm)(PORT=1234)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=exmp)))"

#configure path to installation path of oracle client:
$AssemblyFile = "D:\app\client\product\12.1.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"
$ConnectionString = "User ID=$userName1;Password=$password1;Data Source=$Server1;Persist Security Info=True"
Write-Output "ConnectionString:  $ConnectionString">> $LogFile
$CommandText = "UPDATE  TEST SET id =333 WHERE ID = 3;"

Write-Output $CommandText

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($AssemblyFile) | Out-Null
$OracleConnection = New-Object -TypeName Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
$OracleConnection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$OracleConnection.Open()
$OracleCommand = New-Object -TypeName Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
$OracleCommand1 = New-Object -TypeName Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand
$OracleCommand.CommandText = $CommandText
$OracleCommand.Connection = $OracleConnection
$OracleDataAdapter = New-Object -TypeName Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter
$OracleDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = $OracleCommand
# How do I execute?


$OracleDataAdapter.Dispose()
$OracleCommand.Dispose()
$OracleConnection.Close()
```

Comment: What does "I got stuck" mean? Any error? If so, which one? If not, what is it, then?

Comment: No errors, just don't know how to proceed and run the update statment